# IBM Appscan Security Vulnerability SQL injection

Tags: java, security, jdbc

I have App scan through which i scan my projects but at statements like

```
 preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

there is SQL.Injection Vulnerability , i am using esapi api for setting the value in prepared statement e.g.

```
preparedStatement.setString(1 , OracleEncoder.encode(code) );
```

OracleEncoder is doing This

```
   ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC,param);
```

Any idea how can i fix this Vulnerability?

Comment: you may want to read http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/are-prepared-statements-100-safe-against-sql-injection  it talks about bounding parameters

Comment: @PaulBastide didnt know that existed (security.stackexchange...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing static analysis, appscan does not have a mark up for your ESAPI API, you should create a SQLi validator mark up for your encodeForSQL method in appscan.  That way the next time you scan, the scan engine will pick up the new mark up and understand the SQLi threat is neutralized by the esapi call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encode bind parameters to preparedStatement,

```
// preparedStatement.setString(1 , OracleEncoder.encode(code) ); 
preparedStatement.setString(1 , code );
```

The relevant part of the [`PreparedStatement.setString()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) says,

> The driver converts this to an SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR value (depending on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on VARCHAR values) when it sends it to the database.

Comment: OK got it , and about the IBM app scan Vulnerability because it complains about when i write your way or mine

Comment: @Haider Your way won't work at all. As for the IBM app scan, contact IBM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  ESAPI library function and prepared statement in your code,then you can mark this issues Not an issue.
Prepared statement is one of the mitigation technique to a avoid SQL injection .

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```